# How to catch the exceptions thrown from CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally() while using CompletableFuture.get()?

Tags: java, completable-future

How to catch the exceptions thrown from CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally() while using CompletableFuture.get()?

Here is some code

```
public CompletableFuture<Hello> sayHelloAsync() {
CompletableFuture<Hello> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    try{
        sayHello(); //throws HelloException
    } catch (HelloException ex) {
        future.completeExceptionally(new MyException("hello exception"));
        return future;
    }
    return future;
}

Now I want to do .get() or .join on this as follows
CompletableFuture<Hello> resultFuture = sayHelloAsync();
try{
    result.get(); // throws ExecutionException but I want to catch My Exception in the simplest way possible but not by throwing another exception while catching the Execution exception and so on. 
} catch(ExecutionException ex) {
      throw ex.getCause();
} catch (MyException e) {
      e.printStackTrace() 
}
```

This is very ugly. Again I just want to catch MyException in few lines of code as possible and in the cleanest way possible. Not sure if    isCompletedExceptionally(), exceptionally, join() can help somehow to catch MyException in the easiest way possible. If so how?

Comment: What does the javadoc of `CompletableFuture#get` tell you?

Comment: I says it throws ExecutionException which is not what I want as I specified in the question clearly.

Comment: And what does the javadoc for `ExecutionException` say?

Comment: getCause just throws the throwable and MyException is lost somehow I just tried it. you can't go by docs all the time

Comment: It's not lost. If your future was completed exceptionally, the corresponding exception will be the cause of the `ExecutionException` thrown by `get`.

Comment: thats really ugly. Just edited the question

Comment: So your current code doesn't achieve your intention. The exception thrown by `throw ex.getCause();` won't be caught by the `catch` statement below it. You'll need to wrap the entire `try-catch` statement with another `try-catch`. _Ugly_ is a rather subjective description. This is the access pattern that's offered through `get`. All other answers depend on what you are planning to do with the exception once you have it.

Comment: First I want to get MyException and if I have to wrap .getCause under another try-catch {} that gets even uglier. I am just looking to catch the exception that gets thrown (typical java code) but If I have to use multiple try-catch's and do all that it is mundane. I might need also throw another Exception once I catch the MyException.

Comment: Those are your options.